# Renaming hyperlinks in Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007, how do you rename a hyperlink in an e-mail? Specifically, I want to shorten the URL to something like "CLICK HERE".

Answer (score 1):

Paste in the URL, then right click the URL and select Edit Hyperlink.  Change the "Text to display" field to click here.

BTW, I frown on this behavior on my network.  users should always see what they are about to click.

Comment: +1 I agree with users seeing what they are really clicking on. There are the cases where the url is so long it becomes unclickable however

Answer (score 1):

One more way, type whatever text you want to, select it, press Ctrl+K, paste URL, Done!